# how to find a file is System file or hidden file?

Tags: c#

how to find a file is System file or hidden file ?

for example 'C:\File.txt' is system file or not .
also is it hidden or not ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could use the [GetAttributes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.getattributes.aspx) method:

```
var att = File.GetAttributes(@"c:\file.txt");
if ((att & FileAttributes.Hidden) == FileAttributes.Hidden) 
{
    // the file is hidden
}

if ((att & FileAttributes.System) == FileAttributes.System)
{
    // the file is system
}
```

Comment: How can I find out it is system file or not ?

Comment: Check the `FileAttributes.System` flag like above.

Comment: This will work if FileAttributes are set. Howeverer, it seems they are not in many cases. How do you get this info if FileAttributes  aren't set?